# Using MultiMap to store Financial Market Data in C++

Tags: visual-c++

I would like to understand if MultiMap is the best container in STL to store financial market data with a format like "date","price" (for example 07/10/2013  1000).
I tried to make an simple example, just to understand which could be the implementation but i got an horrible errors when i tried to print them out.

```
  class  Date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    int value_of_date;

  public:
  Date(int d, int m, int y):
      day(d),month(m),year(y){
      value_of_date=year*10000 + month*100 + day;
      }

  friend ostream & operator<< (ostream &out, const Date &date);
  };
      ostream & operator<< (ostream &out, const Date &date) {
        out << "(" << date.day << ", " <<
        date.month << ", " <<
        date.year << ")";
        return out;
    }

  int main () {

     std::multimap<Date,int> first;

     first.insert(std::pair<Date,int>(Date(01,01,2000),1000));
     first.insert(std::pair<Date,int>(Date(01,02,2000),1010));
     first.insert(std::pair<Date,int>(Date(01,03,2000),1020));
     first.insert(std::pair<Date,int>(Date(01,04,2000),1030));

     for(auto i = first.cbegin(); i != first.cend(); i++) {
        std::cout << i->first << " " << i->second << std::endl;
     }
     return 0;
     }
```

Is the comparison < operator() my problem here ? How do i implement < operator() to sort the date.

is there a more elegant solution for a type date instead of using Class Date ?

If this is the best CONTAINER for financial market data ?

Thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 0):

Do you HAVE to do this in C++?  It's a HORRIBLE language to do financial stuff in.  Trust me, I've been there.

If you're trying to add a custom class to a container, you'll need to study the container's requirements for elements.  For example, containers often need to be able to create, delete, compare, sort, and assign values to the things they contain, so you need to implement comparison operators (yes, operator < () is part of it; just implement an operator < (const YourClass& other) const, but read up on your container class), assignment operators, copy constructors, etc.

Which is part of why another language would be easier.  Python, for example, would automatically derive most of those operators for you, AND it was approved by the SEC in the last couple of years as the official language for financial market data.  Python, Java, Ruby, Perl, or just about any other mainstream language, would be a better choice -- especially if it comes with a decimal class.  If you're worried about performance, look into NumPy, and use a database backend like MySQL or mongodb.

But if you DO (believe) you need to use C++ for whatever reason (probably huge data volumes and performance), at least do yourself the courtesy of using boost - especially its variant type, and considering STXXL.  If you want performance, though, go would be a more sensible choice lately.  Really, the only reason to use C++ for this is if you work for a crazy company that forces you to... which does happen.

Comment: Thank you Lee for your suggestion, I will look in a Boost Library and considering STXXL. i need it in C++.